# Can't install O/S from NOOBS

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, memory

Preformatted 8GB micro SD card opens screen to install Raspbian, data partition, or boot from Scratch, but says I have 0 MB of 2762 MB needed, and offers no options to proceed.

Where do I go from here? (It's brand new, 1st boot up.)

Answer (score 1):

**Here are some options:**

1. Re-burn the disk image. You can grab a disk image of your choice from [Raspberry Pi's downloads page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) and the latest copy of Win32DiskImager from [here (direct download link)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download).

   - Simply extract the compressed image, load it up on Win32DiskImager, select the **correct** drive, then **Write** (not read)
2. Nothing else really, except return the card and possibly get another one with the same problem probably caused by outdated software. *Waste of time + waste of effort.*

Comment: Thank you! I reformatted the SD card using a tool provided by CanaKits Tech support, then downloaded fresh copy of NOOBS files from the Rapberry pi website (link also provided by CanaKits tech support). We now have a fully operational machine to play with! The links for the format tool and NOOBs software are:                                                                                                            https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Then, to download the original files to copy onto  the card from here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/